# how to share unpickable object in multiprocessing python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am trying to multiprocessing on a list of _pygit2.Diff objects, which is not pickable . Tried different ways with manager, basemanager, pathos, no luck. 
All yeild 
`TypeError: can't pickle _pygit2.Diff objects`

Example of the pathos version I tried

```
from pathos.multiprocessing import ProcessingPool
results = ProcessingPool(2).map(list_of_diff_objects)
```

Thanks!

Comment: If the non-picklable object has no `.serialize()` method (or something like that...) then a possibility is that you devise a textual/binary representation of the object and your processes act on this representation.

Comment: @gboffi thanks for the reply! you are right, it doesn't have .serialize() method. Could you elaborate on how to devise a textual/binary representation of the object ? Do you mean extract textual/binary attributes that is needed for the multiprocessing from the object and feed those in the loop instead?